# In updatePostalAddress, why does entity-set not have set-if-empty set

Tags: moqui

in line 357-358 of ContactServices.updatePostalAddress:

```
<set field="newPostalAddress" from="origPostalAddress.cloneValue()"/>
<entity-set value-field="newPostalAddress" include="nonpk"/>
```

In my case, address2 had a value in origPostalAddress and does not in the context, so it does not get changed in the entity-set because set-if-empty defaults to false and therefore it is deemed unchanged and no update takes place.

I guess this is a conscious decision not to have fields that are not passed (or empty) affect the update. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a good workaround for this. The update#PartyPostalAddress service in Mantle Business Artifacts is a generic service but with specific behavior, and in this case I think setting set-if-empty=true is fine. This is changed in commit #7e98f27.